# Formatting the returned object from MongoDB/Mongoose group by

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, group-by

I have a MongoDB with documents of the form:

```
{
    ...
    "template" : "templates/Template1.html",
    ...
}
```

where `template` is either `"templates/Template1.html"`, `"templates/Template2.html"` or `"templates/Template3.html"`.

I'm using this query to group by `template` and count how many times each `template` is used:

```
var group = {
        key:{'template':1},
        reduce: function(curr, result){ result.count++ },
        initial: { count: 0 }
    };

    messageModel.collection.group(group.key, null, group.initial, group.reduce, null, true, cb);
```

I'm getting back the correct result, but it's formatted like this:

```
{
    "0" : {
        "template" : "templates/Template1.html",
        "count" : 2 },
    "1" : {
        "template" : "templates/Template2.html",
        "count" : 2 },
    "2" : {
        "template" : "templates/Template3.html",
         "count" : 1 }
}
```

I was wondering if it's possible to change the query so that it returns something like:

```
{
    "templates/Template1.html" : { "count" : 2 },
    "templates/Template2.html" : { "count" : 2 },
    "templates/Template3.html" : { "count" : 1 }
}
```

or even:

```
{
    "templates/Template1.html" : 2 ,
    "templates/Template2.html" : 2 ,
    "templates/Template3.html" : 1
}
```

I would rather change the query and not parse the returned object from the original query.

Comment: To be clear, the returned value from `.group()` and many other operators is actually an "array" of objects and not a singular Object as you represent it. Using "data" as "keys" is also an "anti-pattern" that should be avoided in reusable code and especially data processing. Better alternatives to the very venerable `.group()` option are things such as the aggregation framework. But much in the same way, output is preferred to be a "cursor" and not a singular object. So let databases be databases and mangle your own results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Blakes Seven in the comments you could use [`aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) instead of `group()` to achieve nearly your desired result.

```
messageModel.collection.aggregate([
  { // Group the collection by `template` and count the occurrences
    $group: {
      _id: "$template",
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  { // Format the output
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      template: "$_id",
      count: 1
    }
  },
  { // Sort the formatted output
    $sort: { template: 1 }
  } 
]);
```

The output would look like this:

```
[
  {
    "template" : "templates/Template1.html",
    "count" : 2 },
  {
    "template" : "templates/Template2.html",
    "count" : 2 },
  {
    "template" : "templates/Template3.html",
    "count" : 1 }
  }
]
```

Again, as stated by Blakes in the comments the database can only output an array of objects rather than a solitary object. That would be a transformation that you would need to do outside of the database.

I think it deserves to be restated that this transformation produces an anti-pattern and should be avoided. An object key name provides the context or description for the value.  Using a file location as a key name would be a fairly vague description whereas 'template' provides a bit more information about what that value represents.